# EXCEL isThisWeek()

Tags: excel-formula

I would like a formula that would return true if a given date is in this week, for example:
Lets say Today() is 2/18/2020
I would want it to return true if the GivenDate() is anywhere between 2/16/2020 and 2/22/2020.
I would also like a formula for isNextWeek().

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the expected date is in cell A1, get the previous Monday:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1
```

Get the coming Sunday:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+7
```

You can change the +1 to +8 for the next Monday, and the +7 to +14 for the next Sunday.  So in effect,

```
=IF(AND(A1>=(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1),A1<=(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+7)),"YES","NO")
```

This will return YES if A1 is between Monday and Sunday of this week.

```
=IF(AND(A1>=(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+8),A1<=(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+14)),"YES","NO")
```

This will return YES if A1 is between Monday and Sunday of next week.

I'm certain this can be simplified.

Comment: So how would I implement this to a COUNTIFS statement where I want to count the amount of dates that are in this week?

Comment: @MartinJr.Zacarias Much of that question is wrapped in how your sheet is designed.  I suggest creating a new question with examples of what you have and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

For this week:

```
=AND(WEEKNUM(TODAY())=WEEKNUM(A1),YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR(A1))
```

For Next Week

```
=AND(WEEKNUM(TODAY())+1=WEEKNUM(A1),YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR(A1))
```

One note:  This will fail during the new year change.

[image]

---

For a formula that works no matter if over the new year:

This Week:

```
 =MEDIAN(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+1,TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+7,A1)=A1
```

Next Week:

```
=MEDIAN(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+8,TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+14,A1)=A1
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: So how would I implement this to a COUNTIFS statement where I want to count the amount of dates that are in this week?

Comment: @MartinJr.Zacarias that is a new question, please ask a new question and show what you tried.